# How to run a single command via wsadmin from a Windows batch (.bat) file

Tags: batch-file, websphere

I have been trying to implement a batch file on a Windows server to execute a wsadmin command.

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /K "D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\bin\wsadmin.bat -lang jython -user wasadmin -password wasadmin && $AdminControl invoke $KCLUSTER rippleStart"
```

this logs me into the session but doesn't enter the second part **$AdminControl invoke $KCLUSTER rippleStart**

The image below is where the batch file stops and doesnt go further to enter the **$AdminControl invoke $KCLUSTER rippleStart** part.

[image]

Is there a way to do this using a batch file or another way on a Windows 2012 Server?

Searched the net with no luck to see if this has occured before just dead ends.
I've tried using Call command with no result.

Any direction as to where to go from here is much appreciated

Comment: For one, you're mixing Jacl-like command/variable syntax: `$AdminControl invoke ...` with the fact that you're launching **wsadmin** in *jython* mode.   (Most newer examples and doc use Jython.)    You can launch wsadmin to execute a single command using the `-c` option.   Is that what you're trying to do ?    If so, you just need to get the .bat-file quoting right, which I could probably help with.   I'm not sure though since that raises the question of where you'd get the `kcluster` Jython variable's value from.     Are you trying to enter just this single command or do more (if so what)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Scott.  Yes I'm only trying to execute that command this for the Kcluster.  Kcluster is the name of the cluster in websphere which I've already setup using wsadmin earlier - following the IBM documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/txml_startcluster.html

which would create the kcluster bit.

Comment: Correction: its set as cluster not Kcluster your are correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch wsadmin to execute a single command from a Windows `.bat` file like:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /K ""D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print AdminControl.invoke(kcluster, 'rippleStart')""
```

This changes your original post in three ways.

1. Most recent samples and usages use Jython so I switched to use that.  (You were launching wsadmin with `-lang jython` but using Jacl-like syntax `$AdminControl...`).
2. I used `wsadmin ... -c` to pass a command to execute rather than the `&&` syntax.
3. I used nested quoting to separate the elements of the command.

Of course, this only works assuming you have `kcluster` set previously in the script or wsadmin session.   To see this syntax working "out-of-the-box" you could try something like `AdminApp.list()` like:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /K ""D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print AdminApp.list()""
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm just trying out the solution and it partly works as I attempt the changes but I totally got what you mean and gave me an Awesome Direction.   I will post once I have completed the change

Comment: I've gone back and started the wsadmin in Jython shell and have gone through the setting to set cluster variable to ripple start.  But only in the wsadmin  command line screen. But when I execute the bat file it gives me the following:

**WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminControl.invoke(cluster,'rippleStart'
)"; exception information:
com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in ?
NameError: cluster**

The command works well in command line when I execute:
**AdminControl.invoke(cluster,'rippleStart')**
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not following.. how are you setting the 'cluster' variable ?  Maybe you could paste something showing the complete flow here?

Comment: Apologies Scott the whole process is in the link(supplied at the top) I followed the Jython path in the link.  it works like a charm but the batch file just doesnt execute the ripplestart.  Here is the link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/txml_startcluster.html

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't execute the ripplestart"?   You mean it fails with an exception like WASX7015E?  Ssomething else?  Sorry, I'm still confused about what your script looks like.   Your original question never explained how you were setting the 'cluster' variable.   From the link it seems you know the syntax for building a reference to the Cluster MBean but I'm still not clear how you're setting the cluster variable in this script.     In my answer I was answering the question "how do I run wsadmin executing a one-line command?" but I recognize this isn't your full problem.

Comment: setting the cluster variable is not the issue.  as when I execute the wsadmin command in command line **AdminControl.invoke(cluster, 'rippleStart')** it works fine. its all set.  but when I execute the batch file which contains **@ECHO OFF
cmd /K ""D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\bin\wsadmin.bat" -lang jython -c "print AdminControl.invoke(cluster, 'rippleStart')""** I would get the above error.  I would also run the bat file as Administrator but it comes back with the WASX7015E.

Comment: Figured it out - the **"print AdminControl.invoke(kcluster, 'rippleStart')"** part should be like the following. **print AdminControl.invoke('WebSphere:name=KCLUSTER,process=dmgr,platform=common,node=ctgCellManager01,version=8.5.5.15,type=Cluster,mbeanIdentifier=KCLUSTER,cell=ctgCell01,spec=1.0', 'rippleStart')** this then worked. Thank you for this amazing direction Scott. your a legend!

Comment: Sure..glad it worked out for you!   So basically I showed you how to run an individual command with wsadmin from a .bat file and you figured out how to convert your script into a single command.

Comment: I used the rest of the Administrative Scripting Commands in WebSphere to get the full argument it needed.  Just in case anyone may need it for the future.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question title to make it better match the solution I wrote up.